# Can't get my drawing to show a Triangle with Canvas

Tags: android

**[SOLVED] This is the code that solved my issue:**

```
    triangle = new Path();
    triangle.moveTo(400,200);
    triangle.lineTo(650,650);
    triangle.lineTo(150,650);
    triangle.lineTo(400,200); //NOTE: This last line is not necessary!
```

.

**Problem:**
I have a problem below with getting my Triangle to be visible using canvas. Don't know where I've done wrong in the coding. Any suggestions? Just in case I also tried by reducing the coordinate value to half, in case I was drawing outside the screen. But no luck at all, gave me the same result.

As you can see there's a rectangle already and it works perfectly fine. To give you a idea of the size, the rectangle that is currently drawn is in comparison to the screen very small. So there's plenty of room.

```
public class SquareAndTriangle extends View{

    Path triangle;

    public SquareAndTriangle(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }//SquareAndTriangle context ends here


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect square = new Rect();
        square.set(100,150,200,250);

        triangle = new Path();
        triangle.moveTo(400,400);
        triangle.lineTo(650,650);
        triangle.moveTo(650,650);
        triangle.lineTo(266,650);
        triangle.moveTo(266,650);
        triangle.lineTo(400,400);

        Paint green = new Paint();
        green.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        green.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        Paint red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(Color.RED);
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRect(square,red);
        canvas.drawPath(triangle,green);


    }//canvas ends here

}//SquareAndTriangle(Activity) ends here
```

Comment: and what is `width` and `height` of your canvas? maybe you're drawing outside?

Comment: It wasn't that. I just had to remove the excess "triangle.moveTo" codes. That solved my problem. Posted solution above.